# Are there intuitive/classically algorithmic analogues to Semidefinite programs on networks?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming

Many network optimization algorithms, including shortest path, push-relabel, augmenting path, etc, actually have an interpretation in terms of linear programming.

A famous application of semidefinite programming is the max-cut approximation.
Does this optimization algorithm, or any other on networks, have a network interpretation, a la augmenting path?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are actually after is the elusive *combinatorial interpretation* of SDPs. While this is in general a rather tricky issue, a very nice piece of work that is a good starting point, and brings SDPs closer to combinatorial algorithms is:

[A combinatorial primal-dual approach to semidefinite programs](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/mmw.pdf) by S. Arora and S. Kale.